# Are there any Android e-mail applications that forward intent for an incoming e-mail?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, email

I would like my broadcast receiver to get notified when ever there's a new mail in the inbox. Are there any mail applications that provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K9 mail does https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/wiki/Intents